# Node js - Download and decompress tgz file in memory

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I download the file from https url and decompress .tgz file? Now I download the file and then do the decompression. But I want to do this in the memory. I've tried

```
function downloadFile() {
    var outStream = fs.createWriteStream(config.tgz_file_path);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var req = request(options);
        req.on('response', function (res) {
            if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
                reject(new Error('Status not 200'));
            }
            var encoding = res.headers['content-encoding'];         
            if (encoding == 'gzip') {
                res.pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(outStream);
            } else if (encoding == 'deflate') {
                res.pipe(zlib.createInflate()).pipe(outStream);
            } else {
                res.pipe(outStream);
            }
            res.on('end', function () {
                resolve();
            });
        });
        req.on('error', function(err) {
            throw err;
        });
    });
}
function decompressFile() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        targz.decompress({
            src: config.tgz_file_path,
            dest: './data'
        }, function(err){
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: What problem do you fix if you *do this in memory*? What exactly are you trying to do *in memory* - the download? The result? Your question is unclear.

Comment: I wonder if it would be faster. The tgz file (16mb) is json (45.5mb). After the decompression I upload it to database (elasticsearch).

Comment: I'm sure it's not worth your time, but by the looks of your code - you need to create writable memory stream. Googling for "node.js writable memory stream" will give you the packages you need, code adjustment is trivial - good luck.